# Name and Title on separate lines in Modern CV

Tags: line-spacing, moderncv

Basically I want to have the Name and Title sections in Modern CV on separate lines and not have the "|" separator. I figured out that to get rid of the separator I can just remove it in the moderncvbanking.sty file and then I replace it with \newline.

Problem is the text is now off centre, how could I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Modifying `moderncvstylebanking.sty` file itself, is a very very bad idea. Don't do it!*

Add the following to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
    \makeatletter
    \xpatchcmd{\maketitle}{\titlestyle{~|~\@title}}{\par\vskip1ex\titlestyle{\@title}}{}{}
    \makeatother
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[scale=0.85]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\title{Banking Executive}
\address{Address line 1}{Address line 2}
\mobile{Phone}
\email{Email}
\social[linkedin]{linkedin}
\social[github]{github}
\quote{Some quote}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\maketitle}{\titlestyle{~|~\@title}}{\par\vskip1ex\titlestyle{\@title}}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\section{Section}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In current (2016) versions of `moderncv`, `\maketitle` has to be replaced by `\makehead` in the patch command, i.e., the line now reads `\xpatchcmd{\makehead}{\titlestyle{~|~\@title}}{\par\vskip1ex\titlestyle{\@title}}{}{}`

Comment: By the way, this shows that it is no bad idea at all to modify a local copy of a style file: The modified local version will stay around indefinitely and the document can be typeset also 10 years later, whereas the above patch broke when the global `moderncv` class/style was replaced by a new version (breaking also the document). And I'm sure that sooner or later my patch of the patch will also be outdated.

Answer (score 2):

Addendum to Harish Kumar's solution: In current (2016) versions of moderncv, `\maketitle` has to be replaced by `\makehead` in the patch command, i.e., the modification in the preamble now reads

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\makehead}{\titlestyle{~|~\@title}}{\par\vskip1ex\titlestyle{\@title}‌​}{}{}
\makeatother
```