# Separate text in two lines

Tags: line-breaking, titles, moderncv

I started taking a CV Template which I need to edit. This one:
https://es.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/moderncv-classic

So It turns that my name is longer than "John Doe". If I go to the editor, `main.txt`, and find the line 26

```
% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
```

and change it to

```
% personal data
\name{John}{Martinez Rodriguez}
```

You can see that now the name stays like this, in the document:

```
John Martinez
Rodriguez
```

And I want it to appear like

```
John 
Martinez Rodriguez
```

Could you help me with this, please?

Comment: Please see my answer to this (duplicate?) question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/302881/16550

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of possibilities. I don't know the template, so you have to decide for yourself what is the best solution:

### Possibility 1

Add `\\` in front of `M` in Martinez. This adds a line break before your last name. Also if it occurs elsewhere! Your last name will still be split if too long.

### Possibility 2

Put your last name in a `mbox`: `\name{John}{\mbox{Martinez Rodriguez}}`. Your last name will never be split but rather overlap other text.

### Possibility 3

Use `~` as a non-breaking space in your name. Probably you will have to take care of hyphenation of your name though. You can do this by e.g. setting `\hyphenpenalty` to `10000`.

Comment: Tha'ts a perfect answer. Thank you very much!!