# Modern CV Banking, title and name on different lines

Tags: moderncv

I have a problem with `moderncv` banking. I'd like to put my name and the title on different lines. There are some solutions on the subjects, but they did not work fine for me unfortunately. Here is a solution I have found here (I tried it but didn't work so far):

[Name and Title on separate lines in Modern CV](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198742/name-and-title-on-separate-lines-in-modern-cv)

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.85, top=1.5cm, bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\name{John}{Smith}
\title{Engineering Degree} 
\phone[mobile]{00.00.00.00}
\email{john.smith@blabla.com}
\social[linkedin]{john-smith}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\maketitle}{\titlestyle{~|~\@title}}{\par\vskip1ex\titlestyle{\@title}}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Comment: In the `\xpatchcmd`, replace `\maketitle` by `\makehead`, such that the line starts with `\xpatchcmd{\makehead}{\titlestyle`... The problem with patches is that they stop working as soon as the internals of the patched code change. Apparently code that was in the macro `\maketitle` has been moved to `\makehead` in a later version.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked perfectly. So if I undertood correctly what you said about the internals of the patched code, if it changes again, it is possible that this solution wouldn't work. But thanks again. Best solution

Comment: Please see my answer to question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/317219/banking-style-of-moderncv-doesnt-reconize-makecvheadnamewidth-for-fiting-long?rq=1

Comment: @gernot Please, add an answer.

Comment: @egreg Done, answer added.

Answer (score 2):

The solution proposed in [Name and Title on separate lines in Modern CV](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/198745/110998) still works, but with a small modification: Replace `\maketitle` by `\makehead` in the patch command such that the extra code in the preamble reads

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\makehead
   {\titlestyle{~|~\@title}}%
   {\par\vskip1ex\titlestyle{\@title}}%
   {}{}
\makeatother
```

The problem with patches is that they stop working as soon as the internals of the patched code change. Apparently code that before was in the macro `\maketitle` has been moved to `\makehead` in later versions.

Here is a complete example.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.85, top=1.5cm, bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\name{John}{Smith}
\title{Engineering Degree} 
\phone[mobile]{00.00.00.00}
\email{john.smith@blabla.com}
\social[linkedin]{john-smith}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\makehead
   {\titlestyle{~|~\@title}}%
   {\par\vskip1ex\titlestyle{\@title}}%
   {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Naoufal , Try this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.85]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\name{\hspace{2.48cm}John}{Smith}
\title{\Large{}\newline{}\vspace{-0.24cm}\newline{}Engineering Degree}
% You can play with \hspace*{1.89cm}     and \vspace     and \newline
\phone[mobile]{00.00.00.00}
\email{john.smith@blabla.com}
\social[linkedin]{john-smith}

\begin{document}
\newgeometry{top=1.25cm, bottom=1.02cm,right=1.61cm, left=1.61cm}% inner=1cm, outer=0.618\textwidth
\vspace*{-1.02cm}
\maketitle
\vspace*{-0.88cm}
\end{document}
```

You should sesarch the way to erase the vertical line after the name and surname.

You obtain this:

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't we strive for minimally invasive operations instead of big hammers, like in medicine?

Comment: @gernot ok I just wrote in the way I think my post could help more. In the line of the original question.

Comment: My feeling is that searching *the way to erase the vertical line* is beyond the abilities we can expect from a standard user of LaTeX.

Comment: @gernot I´m not a profesional of LaTeX, I´m a user that tried to help another one. Only that. I think that all of us should know more :-) but ... the best way is know the opinion of the original question writer. I think that you try to explain how to erase that vertical line ;-)

Comment: Thank you guys, but gernot's solution worked just fine. Simple and efficient