# ModernCV - Remove vertical line in \makecvtitle

Tags: moderncv

Any suggestions on removing the vertical line between name and title using ModernCV style banking? Looks very weird in case of a long name.

[image]

I got to the [styling document](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/moderncvstylebanking.sty) but haven't been able to understand it.

Minimal code to reproduce:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{burgundy}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\name{This is a very long name}{A}
\title{\newline Curriculum Vit\ae{}}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you post a full, yet minimal code that we can play with?

Comment: @Bernard Added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My answer is based on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/325539/modern-cv-banking-title-and-name-on-different-lines/344591#344591), credit should always be given. The solution will fulfill your requirement and will also eliminate the need to use `\newline` in the title.

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{burgundy}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\makehead
   {\titlestyle{~|~\@title}}%
   {\newline\newline\titlestyle{\@title}}%
   {}{}
\makeatother
\name{This is a very long name}{A}
\title{Curriculum Vit\ae{}}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm generally onboard with the whole "Google your issue with TeX, find some random script on SO, paste it, it works magically, you have no idea why" train, but mind explaining what this does? I presume you patch the `makehead` command, which is somewhere inside `makecvtitle`, but how did you get this syntax?

Comment: Sure! If you go and visit [2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter header: 6](https://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/moderncvheadvi.sty), there will be `\@initializecommand{\makehead}{%` ... is the command that controls the title which is what we want to change. Now,  we patch it via [`\xpatchcmd`](https://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/xpatch/xpatch.pdf#section.0.4) which is `\xpatchcmd{<command>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}`. That is all! Hopefully it make sense.

Answer (score 0):

It is not an elegant answer, but it works:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{burgundy}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\name{This is a very long name}{A\tikzmark{a}}
\title{\newline Curriculum Vit\ae{}}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \fill[white] ([yshift=-.2cm]pic cs:a) rectangle +(1,.9);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image: Screenshot]